# Scale Text in overlay without blurring

Tags: swiftui

I've got a `Text()` in an `overlay()`. After applying `.scaleEffect()`, the text becomes blurry/aliased:

[image]

How can I make the text remain sharp? - I want the green Rectangle and Text to scale with the yellow Rectangle

(This is a simplified version of a complex UI element with nested overlays. Moving the overlay below scaleEffect is not an option.)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ZoomFontView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 100)
            .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            .overlay(sub_view)
            .scaleEffect(6) // Placeholder for MagnificationGesture
    }
    
    var sub_view: some View {
        ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(maxWidth: 70, maxHeight: 70)
            .foregroundColor(Color.mint)
            .overlay(Text("Hello"))
        }
    }
}

struct ZoomFontView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZoomFontView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `scaleEffect` scale view like an image, instead you have to scale background and text separately, scaling font for `Text` so it is rendered properly.

Here is a demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 13.1 / iOS 15.1

[image: demo1][image: demo2]

left: scale = 1 right: scale = 8

```
struct ZoomFontView: View {

    let scale: CGFloat = 8
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 100)
            .foregroundColor(Color.mint)
            .scaleEffect(1 * scale) // Placeholder for MagnificationGesture
            Text("Hello").font(.system(size: 18 * scale))
                .fixedSize()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and yes that's possible of course. But, I have a complex UI with nested overlays, so I cannot use ZStacks instead. Is there another workaround?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect the constraints

Answer (score 1):

Both text and Images are rendered in a low level CoreAnimation layer that relies on GPU rendering (aka Metal) to display as bitmap based graphics. So if you scale a layer where the text is being rendered, it will have the same effect of scale an Image, in other words, it will upscale pixels and make it try to "anti alias" the text to make the edges smoother.

So you should not have to scale the layer directly, instead, you should scale the `font` in order to archive the proper result.

```swift
Text("Hello")
  // scale is the scale factor you're applying to the layer.
  .font(.system(size: 16 * scale))
```