# How to use scaleEffect with TextEditor in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to use `scaleEffect` to scale a `TextEditor` contained in a `VStack`. When not scaled the text editor is very normal. But After scaling the editor can not be edited normally as the cursor can not be placed in the right place. Here is the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DemoTextView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var scale: Double = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                TextEditor(text: $text)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .top)
                    .border(Color.red)
            }
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Slider(value: $scale, in: 0.25...4)
                Text("\(scale)")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct DemoTextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoTextView()
    }
}
```

And the screenshot of the wired behavior:

[image: demo]

Anyone knows how to make the scaling of `TextEditor` works?

Comment: The scalleEffect scales only visual representation the view's frame (in this case TextEditor) stays the same, so tappable area stays the same. It is no clear what you try to do by scalleEffect is not appropriate tool for that.

Comment: I want to scale the all the contents in VStack which contains the TextEditor. So I try to use scaleEffect and it do scale all the contents. And after scaling I want the TextEditor to be editable as normal.

Comment: You should not, at least with text editor (background can be scaled), instead operate with frame and font size, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70187913/12299030.

Comment: @maralla: There is a way without using .scaleEffect(), using frame.